# Proving the Well Ordering Property of $\mathbb{Z}$ by induction and prove the minimal element is unique.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I would like a verification of this proof. (Am I using induction?)
Claim: $\mathbb{Z}$ is well ordered and there exists a unique minimal element.
Assumptions: There are no repeated members in $\mathbb{Z}$. (Is this a fair assumption?)

Let $A = \{ n_1,n_2,n_3,...n_k\}$.

to order $A$, one can test the minimum of each neighbor element.

$A = \{min(n_1,n_2), min(n_2,n_3), min(n_3,n_4),...min(n_{k-2},n_{k-1}),min(n_{k_1},n_k)\}$

The first element of $A$ is then the minimum $m$. If $m$ is not unique such that an equivalent element $c = m$, $A$ would have repeating members.

Let $\mathbb{Z} = \{Z_i~|~i \in I\}$ if each element of $\mathbb{Z}$ is arranged like $A$, then $\mathbb{Z} = \cup Z_i$ makes $\mathbb{Z}$ well ordered.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}$ is not well-ordered ; $\mathbb{N}$ is.

Comment: Also, nowhere does what the set actually is seem to enter the proof.

Comment: @CaptainLama they're the same set, are they not?

Comment: @Obliv Well, there are negative numbers...

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft should I just say $\mathbb{Z}$ is the set of all integers?

Comment: Basically, what you are trying to do here is proving that in a totally ordered set, any finite subset has a unique least element. This is different from showing something is well-ordered.